# Browsersync doesn't detect changes on sass files in the subfolders

Tags: sass, gulp

I have a gulp task to build css files from sass files as following:

```
gulp.task("sass", () => {
  return (
    gulp.src([
      src_assets_folder + "sass/*.scss"
      ], {
        since: gulp.lastRun("sass"),
      })
      .pipe(debug({title: "sass-debug:"}))
      .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
      .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: onError}))
      .pipe(dependents())
      .pipe(sass({ fiber: Fiber }))
      .pipe(autoprefixer())
      .pipe(minifyCss())
      .pipe(sourcemaps.write("."))
      .pipe(gulp.dest(dist_folder))
      .pipe(browserSync.reload({ stream: true }))
  );
});
gulp.watch([src_assets_folder + 'sass/**/*.scss'], gulp.series("sass"));
```

The sass files I'm building are the ones found immediately under sass folder and not all the files that are in the sass subfolders, but my watcher is on all the files inside the sass folder recursivly.

The problem I'm having is that when Browsersync is up, and then I update a sass file that is not found immediately under sass folder, Browsersync doesn't detect any changes, but when I update a sass file that is found immediately under sass folder, Browsersync detects the changes.

How can I solve that?

Comment: I am a little confused - do your `sass/*.scss` files @import or @use all the sass files found at a greater depth?

Comment: @Mark yes exactly, my `sass/*.scss` only includes sass files inside subfolders, they actually don't contain any sass code.

Comment: And are these included files all partials, so start with underscores?

Comment: @Mark no they don't, but they are all in subfolders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found a solution on how to fix my issue.

The idea is to include the partials in the task src and then filter them to prevent building them.

The final solution looks like this:

```
gulp.task("sass", () => {
  const partials = readdirSync(src_sass_folder, { withFileTypes: true })
    .filter(dirent => dirent.isDirectory())
    .map(dirent => `!${src_sass_folder + dirent.name}/**/*.scss`);
  return (
    gulp.src([
        src_sass_folder + "*.scss",
        src_sass_folder + "**/*.scss"
      ], {
        since: gulp.lastRun("sass"),
      })
      .pipe(dependents())
      .pipe(filter(['**'].concat(partials))) // =====================> HERE
      .pipe(debug({title: "sass-debug:", showCount: false}))
      .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
      .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: onError}))
      .pipe(sass({ fiber: Fiber }))
      .pipe(autoprefixer())
      .pipe(minifyCss())
      .pipe(sourcemaps.write("."))
      .pipe(gulp.dest(dist_folder + "Content"))
      .pipe(browserSync.stream({match: '**/*.css'}))
  );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be related to the `since` option of [`src()`](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/src). With that option enabled, that task doesn't create any Vinyl objects to pipe unless there are detectable changes in the files immediately under sass folder since the last time the task was run. Removing that option should fix the issue.

Comment: By removing that, the sass task rebuilds all the sass files and not only the one that got changed, this takes a lot of time and in my case it's 23s

Comment: In order to use `since` and still have the task fully run and update browsersync, you'll need to change the `src()` path to `sass/**/*.scss`, which creates its own issues.

Comment: Yeah that's not an option I'm afraid, that will build all the included sass files as well.

Comment: @RenaudisNotBillGates That's how it works though, and this answer fully answers the question as written.

Comment: wouldn't that be weird? since a lot of projects have sass partials included in the main sass files, I don't think they build the partials as well, since that won't work in the first place if some used variables are declared in another separated partial.

Comment: I think most projects don't use `since` with sass for this reason